# PHP script keeps throwing errors pertaining to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so i'm working on a simple script that puts form data into a MySQL DB then lists it on list.php page. I'm having trouble with 2 files that this script uses, one being the insert.php page that take form data and inputs it into the DB, and list.php that gets the information from the DB and puts it into a table. insert.php is saying "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, keyw, htags) VALUES ('example.com' at line 1", here is the code for the insert.php script: Script too large, pastebin link- http://pastebin.com/VWSywNA0
here's the code for list.php which keeps giving the error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\list.php on line 37
", code too large pastebin link- http://pastebin.com/R1aRkd2m

Anyway's any help is greatly appreciated, i really need help with this, i've searched Google and other solutions many times.

Comment: What stops you from posting only line 37 of the code here? And by the way `desc` is a reserved word

Comment: Please post your code *here*, not on 3rd party sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESC` is a keyword. Wrap it in grave accents "`" or, better yet, rename the column.